# Cascade Carnot cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

In a Carnot cycle about 50% of the energy is converted in work whereas the other is dissipated in heat to the heat sources.

**Is it possible to reuse the heat in another cycle to reconvert 50% of it into work?**

If so, it would theoretically be possible to eventually convert all the initial energy into work since :

$\underset{n=1}\Sigma (\frac{1}{2})^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}-1=1$ .

However, I fell this is not possible since only the free energy F = U-TS of the original gas should be convertible into work.

Comment: "In a Carnot cycle about 50% of the energy is converted in work whereas the other is dissipated in heat to the heat sources." Why 50%?

Comment: To do this, you need to have subsequent cycle heat sinks at lower and lower temperatures.  How far do you think you have such heat sinks available?

Comment: @noah it is about 50% the exact theoretical value being $\eta = 1-\frac{T_c}{T_h}$ where $T_h$ and $T_c$ are the heat source constant temperatures.

Comment: I know the efficiency of the Carnot cycle, but why would you assume that the hot bath is twice as hot as the cold one?

Comment: @ChesterMiller that's a good point. Indeed, 3 or 4 stages already bring the temperature of the cold source very low. In practice, though how many stages are being used?

Comment: @noah I was just taken so reference values.

Comment: So after the first cycle your energy is in the cold bath. To extract it, you need an even colder bath. If you had such a colder bath, why not use it for the first cycle right away and increase its efficiency?

Comment: Because to maintain the cold bath to its temperature you need to dissipate the extra heat energy. What I was saying is why not reuse this energy ? Basically, in a car engine, the engine is the cool bath >150°C and the coldest bath you could get is 20°C so there should theoretically be some space for improvement with another stage.

Comment: H, now I see where you are going. Well yes, in principle, that is possible, and the efficiency you get is exactly the same as for a single Carnot cycle operating at the hottest and coldest bath temperatures available, as per the formula you gave earlier.

Comment: Once you get to about 20 C, you're really going to run out of natural sinks.  Yeah, you can use ice from the poles, but this really becomes impractical.  You can't create man-made sinks, since this will require loss of overall efficiency.

Comment: yes I get it Thanks for both. Even if for some technological reasons it could necessary to have several stages, it theory one stage is enough and the best you can get is the theoretical carnot yield. Does that mean that a power station would be more efficient in space which is at 3K?